# Frechet differentiable implies reflexive?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Is it true that if dual norm of $X^*$  is Frechet differentiable then $X$ is reflexive?
Can any one help me?
thanks

Comment: I think that finite dimensional $l^p$ spaces are already a counter-example. The norm is not differentiable at zero. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ Dear  Benjamin Dickman , thanks, your answer is very perfect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is true. See **[Theorem 8.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hcqm4_lW4EkC&pg=PA244)** in:

> Fabian, M. J. (Ed.). (2001). Functional analysis and infinite-dimensional geometry (Vol. 8). Springer.

[image]

(Lemma 8.4 not visible in Google Books.) The citations for the above are:

> [Jam2] James, R. C. (1964). Weak compactness and reflexivity. Israel Journal of Mathematics, 2(2), 101-119.

and

> [Dis2] Diestel, J. (1984). Sequences and series in Banach spaces (Vol. 13). Berlin Heidelberg New York: Springer.

---

Alternatively, see Corollary 2.3 in:

> Haghshenas, H. (2009). A Compilation of some Well-Known Results in Renorming Theory. arXiv preprint **[arXiv:0901.3029](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3029.pdf)**.

(Here the author proves the stated fact as a consequence of Smulian’s theorem, which is mentioned in the comments above.)

Other classical results can also be found in:

> Diestel, J. (1975). Geometry of Banach spaces: selected topics (Vol. 485). Berlin: Springer-Verlag.

(I think this particular fact is again proved on p. 33.)